# Extract the background Color/Drawable from a TypedValue

Tags: android, resources, styles

I'm working on an Android project, and trying to retrieve the window title background style and then extract the background color/drawable (so I can apply them to my custom titlebar layout). I've been able to get to a TYPE_REFERENCE for the style using this code:

```
    TypedValue a = new TypedValue();
            getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowTitleBackgroundStyle, a, true);
            if(a.type == TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE){
    // GOES IN HERE
// Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(a.resourceId); // THROWS A RESOURCES NOT FOUND EXCEPTION
    }
```

I'm coming up blank (despite easily 2 hours of attempted spells in Google) of how to successfully figure out what the resource that a points to is and going from there to a color/Drawable. I'm assuming it is a style defined in XML somewhere: how can I actually fetch the properties/attributes/settings of that style programmatically and get the color/Drawable attached for the background?

Answer (score 5):

Ah, figured it out:

```
TypedValue a = new TypedValue();
getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowTitleBackgroundStyle, a, true);
        if(a.type == TypedValue.TYPE_REFERENCE){
            TypedArray b = this.obtainStyledAttributes(a.resourceId, new int[]{
                    android.R.attr.background
            });
            b.getValue(0, a);
                        titleBar.setBackgroundResource(a.resourceid);
            b.recycle();
        }
```